# How can I use both PHPUnit dependency feature and Laravel WithTransactions trait?

Tags: testing, laravel-5, phpunit

In Laravel, there's a trait called `DatabaseTransactions` which rolls back all transactions made by a test, to keep the database clean and isolated. It's fine and useful.

But there's a feature in PHPUnit called [Test Dependencies](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#test-dependencies) in which you can use another test's output:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function a_producer_test()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    return $user;
}

/**
 * @test
 * @depends a_producer_test
 */
public function a_consumer_test(User $user)
{
    $id = $user->id;
}
```

When using `DatabaseTransactions`, you cannot use `$user` inside `a_consumer_test` because the transaction that created the user is rolled back and thus `$user` is empty. If you remove `use DatabaseTransactions;` from the test class, everything works fine and you can use `$user`.

Now I want to have `$user` inside my `a_consumer_test` method, yet I want to roll back transactions and clean my database after execution of the tests. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an in-memory SQLite database then you won't have to rollback the transactions. You can simple add the following lines to you `phpunit.xml` file:

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

The database would only be created for the tests and then it would be destroyed after the tests have run.